# Wait for information before running controllers

Tags: angularjs

I've got this in my main controller

```
UserInfo.getInfo().then(() => {
        ctrl.myUser = UserInfo.getCurrentUser();
    });
```

But I have other controllers that rely on this data, so when I reload a page with another controller that needs `ctrl.myUser.id` it says can't find id of undefined.

How can make the other controllers on my page to wait until `ctrl.myUser` is defined?

Thank you

Comment: Use  route resolvers. If you still don't use a router, this is a very good reason to change this.

Comment: It must be a big page to have multiple controllers - unless you're talking about directive controllers? If not, why not roll all the 'page' controllers into one?

Comment: perhaps you can consider using service. the service simply returns a promise and you can use this promise everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to assign result on success:

```
ctrl.myUser = UserInfo.getCurrentUser();
```

instead the above code, use as like the below code,

```
UserInfo.getCurrentUser().then(function(response)){
     ctrl.myUser = response.data;
}, function(response){
     //do some error handling
});
```